# Azure B2 - jit migration failing to authenticate user on password reset - all configured using custom policies

Tags: azure, migration, azure-ad-b2c, jit, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So I have been involved in implementing Azure B2C using custom policies.

I've tried to follow jit v2 migration process from this git repo https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/jit-migration-v2

So the legacy system is .net framework 4.6.2 and MS SQL database. I have managed to implement all functionalities needed for B2C with the help of owin libraries.

So B2C is supposed to redirect users back to our website after the forgot password process and it does redirect but the user is not authenticated. Instead, we’re getting this generic error:

"OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: 'server_error'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.
Correlation ID: d38ccb08-4c77-4716-97e0-465f0aebfeb6
Timestamp: 2021-08-09 08:34:22Z
'. Error_Uri (may be empty): 'error_uri is null'."

I need to say that forgot password process with authenticated redirect back works all fine when the user is already migrated to B2C. The problem only happens when the user is a non-migrated user. Both scenarios are using the same custom policies except some ValidationTechnicalProfile are conditional on whether the user has been migrated or not.

Here is piece of our custom policy that is responsible for password reset process:

```
<!-- PASSWORD RESET first page -->
     <TechnicalProfile Id="PasswordResetFirstPage">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <!--  NOTE: Remove the validation technical profile to the extension policy -->
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" ContinueOnError="true" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-PasswordReset1" ContinueOnError="false" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <!-- PASSWORD RESET second page -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PasswordResetSecondPage">
      <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />

      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <!--  NOTE: Remove the validation technical profile to the extension policy -->
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
          <!--Don't run this validation technical profile if objectId is not exists (migrated acccount)-->
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-PasswordReset2">
           <!--Don't run this validation technical profile if objectId is exists (existing acccount)-->
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-MigrateUserUsingLogonEmail">
          <!--Don't run this validation technical profile if objectId is exists (existing acccount)-->
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-PasswordUpdate" ContinueOnError="false" />
     </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Generally the whole process works fine: user is migrated to B2C and password is reset but the actual redirect back to our website is just not authenticated. So far the only workaround we have managed to implement is to just redirect user back to login page but it would be nice to understand what's going on and fix it.

I also need to mention that the same migration step works fine for non-migrated users that want to sign in and there is no problem with that scenario.

We have contacted azure support and we already had few calls with them but it looks like they don't know why this happens and they have not been able to help us sort this out.

Any suggestions very appriciated.

Comment: Would you be able to configure Application Insights in an Azure subscription and set it on the policy? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights This might give you more insight into the actual errors.

Comment: @junnas yes we have managed to implement it and we're getting exactly the same generic error logged there as well :\